# Is molecular dynamics relevant for an undergraduate Mechanical Engineering degree?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering, chemistry

I am completing my final year undergraduate study in Mechanical Engineering. I've had to have a scope change because my last project was not going to work with the pandemic. I've been given a project in molecular dynamics by my supervisor to be completed in 2 months (slightly reduced scope). I wanted an outside opinion on whether molecular dynamics falls under mechanical engineering.

Comment: I think molecular dynamics is useful to mechanical engineers in certain types of applications. Could you tell us more about your particular project?

Comment: Your supervisor has found a project for you to complete your degree. If you insist on a change now you will have even less time.

Comment: This looks like an [academic guidance question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/1832). Such questions often involve personal choice and can probably be better answered by an adviser or counselor. We do not believe this site's format is well-suited to such questions, which are therefore considered off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is very difficult anymore to get to anything truly novel without mixing different disciplines. For example, its difficult to imagine, advances in molecular treatments, without the interaction of biologists, statisticians, engineers (electrical, mechanical and chemical).

So in my opinion compartmentalization of disciplines is something that limits the advance of knowledge. So in that respect, I believe that you should be open to different experiences and fields of study.

**Suggestion**: Like SolarMike suggested, you are in a tight spot. If you are remotely interested in the subject, I'd suggest take the bullet and complete it to the best of your abilities. Final year projects are rarely important to the professional career. I think your supervisor, is *probably* trying to get you out of the tight spot, so you should take up the offer.